# manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, azure, docker, kubernetes, azure-aks

I am deploying a Microservice on azure through GitHub actions, the pod is the `CrashLoopBackOff`  status

here are logs command output from the Kubernetes namespace and the container is the crashbackoffloop

is there is something to be done with volumes?? per some search people are compiling about that

```html
 kubectl logs --previous --tail 10  app-dev-559d688468-8lr6n  
 
/usr/local/bin/python: can't open file '/app/3/ON_ /Scripts/manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

```html
 
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name:  app-dev
  namespace: dev
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app:  app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name:  -app
          image: "${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/app:${IMAGE_TAG}"
          readinessProbe:
            failureThreshold: 6
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: 8000
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            periodSeconds: 30
            successThreshold: 1
            timeoutSeconds: 1
          imagePullPolicy: Always

      

 
          command: ["/bin/sh"]
          args:
            - -c
            - >-
                /bin/sed -i -e "s/# 'autodynatrace.wrappers.django'/'autodynatrace.wrappers.django'/" /app/T /ON_ 3/ON_  /settings.py &&
                /usr/local/bin/python manage.py collectstatic --noinput &&
                AUTOWRAPT_BOOTSTRAP=autodynatrace AUTODYNATRACE_FORKABLE=True /usr/local/bin/gunicorn --workers 8 --preload --timeout 120 --config gunicorn.conf.py --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
          env:
            - name: AUTODYNATRACE_POD_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  apiVersion: v1
                  fieldPath: metadata.name
            - name: AUTODYNATRACE_APPLICATION_ID
              value: Django ($(AUTODYNATRACE_POD_NAME):8000)
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000
          volumeMounts:
           
          - name: secrets
            readOnly: true
            mountPath: /root/FHIREngine/conf
          - name: secrets
            readOnly: true
            mountPath: /home/ view/FHIREngine/conf
      imagePullSecrets:
         
        - name: docker-registry-credentials
      volumes:
       - name: secrets
         secret:
            secretName:   config
            defaultMode: 420
      restartPolicy: Always
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name:  app
  namespace: dev
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name:  app
      port: 8000
      targetPort: 8000
  selector:
    app:  app
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app
  namespace:  dev
  annotations:
    #external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname:  .io
    #external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/type: external
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx-internal
spec:
  rules:
    - host:  com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              # serviceName: app
              # servicePort: 8000
              service:
                name:  app
                port:
                  number: 8000
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```

the same image is working fine on aws side

```html
kubectl describe pod

Events:
  Type     Reason   Age                    From     Message
  ----     ------   ----                   ----     -------
  Warning  BackOff  13m (x681 over 157m)   kubelet  Back-off restarting failed container
  Normal   Pulling  3m27s (x36 over 158m)  kubelet  Pulling image " applicationA:latest"
```

let me know any ideas

Comment: Add the yaml related to your gh action

Comment: added the manifest file in the question

Answer (score 0):

Pod `CrashLoopBackOff` status indicates that pod startup fails repeatedly in Kubernetes.

**Possible workaround I :**

1)**OOMKiller :** You will also likely see `Reason: OOM` in the container in the `/app/3/ON_ /Scripts/manage.py` output. Check if your application needs more resources.
1)Check that your `manage.py` file should be located in the root directory of the project. Make sure you need to be in the directory that `manage.py` is in. Also check if there are any errors in the name of the file.

2)Check If the `liveness probe failed`, you can see a warning like `‘manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory` in the events output, So adjust the time for the liveness/readiness probes, See D[efine readiness probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-readiness-probes) for more information.

Please refer to this [link](https://containersolutions.github.io/runbooks/posts/kubernetes/crashloopbackoff/#solution-e) for more detailed information.

**Possible Workaround 2 :**

Based on the `warning :: reason: Backoff, message: Back-off restarting failed container`

As you mentioned container `restartPolicy: Always`, recommending to change the container `restartPolicy: OnFailure`, this should mark the pod status completed once the process/command ends in the container.

Refer to Kubernetes official [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#restart-policy) for more information.